# Why isn't my website responsive anymore after adding domain?

Tags: html, angular, dns, aws-amplify

I have made a simple website for a event in my town and it is hosted on AWS Amplify from Amazon. At first there was no custom domain coupled to it and so the domain name was some random url. On this url the website worked, for web and mobile. But then I asked the previous domain owner if he could couple the custom domain to this site. He did the but when I opened the website on my phone it wasn't responsive anymore, it was shown the same way as on web. 
I then checked the AWS Amplify console and saw that the SSL verification failed. I'd think that it only causes the website to be hhtp instaid of hhtps but could this problem be related?
Or could the problem be a setting in the dns file or something?

I saw some similar problems were because this line wasn't added :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but I made the website with Angular and this line is automaticly added to the index.html file.

my previous responsive website: https://master.dkog5qeqqzcy6.amplifyapp.com/

the unresponsive website: http://www.tongerloleeft.be/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Being inside an iframe is a big problem and would affect it a lot. If you can try take it out and just use the bare code.

Comment: I'll ask the domain owner if he could change it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console looks clean, the page appears to be responsive on my end(using chrome, Firefox and Chrome Edge desktop revs.)

It's not responsive on native Andriod because the @media screen size appears to be responding at less than 640 and the default viewport of a mobile is 640 so it's never getting hit.

Also..... Why are you running it in a frameset?

```
<frameset rows="100%,0" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" framecolor="#000000">
        <frame src="https://master.dkog5qeqqzcy6.amplifyapp.com">
    </frameset>
```

I'd say that is the problem. Not viewport size after having a second look.

Comment: I'm not the one who added the domain to the website but i'll ask the owner if he could change this so that it isn't in a frameset. Hopefully that's the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is also responsive for me you could be using Microsoft Edge Legacy if so I recommend updating it. I have just used the new Microsoft Edge to view this as well as Chrome.

You can update here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge

You can also use (if you are not already using) Developer Tools in Chrome and Edge to view screen sizes of devices. You can use the shortcut keys Ctrl, Shift, I

Comment: It is also responsive to me in my browser but on my phone it isn't

Comment: have you tried using the developer tools and setting it to a phone? Could help in the future.